# queryset not loaded in ModelSelect2Widget in Django Select2

Tags: django, jquery-select2

Here is my database:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Subject(models.Model):
   title=models.CharField(max_length=25)
   marks = models.FloatField()
   student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student,
        related_name='student',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
```

Now I want to use Django select 2 to view those details in Django admin panel.

Here is my form:

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    student = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Student.objects.all(),
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=Student,
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
        )
    )

    subject = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Subject.objects.all(),
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=Subject,
            search_fields=['title__icontains'],
            dependent_fields={'student': 'student'},
        )
    )
```

I want to select each student and select each subject, but I am getting this output:

[image: My Output]

I cannot view anything

Comment: Can you share your HTML also

Comment: actually i am trying to do it through admin.py . Is it necessary to make a html file?

Comment: i feel my queryset is not loaded can you help me with it

Comment: did you manage to solve this?  your example was the thing that got me closest to seeing anything at all.  I'm doing this from an own html, but there's no html there, it's just plain a form object, handled to the renderer and translated into a string.

Comment: maybe useful, this is the produced html: `<tr><th><label for="id_accession">Accession:</label></th><td><select name="accession" class="django-select2 django-select2-heavy" data-ajax--type="GET" id="id_accession" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-ajax--cache="true" data-allow-clear="false" data-ajax--url="/select2/fields/auto.json" data-field_id="MTQwNTE1NzY1Mzg1OTI4:1hLpuc:1suqrRkIuJPapaosXDsnKE3P_Pw" required></select></td></tr>`

Comment: @mariotomo yes i solved it

Comment: what about providing your own answer to your own question?

Comment: This was actually jquery is not loaded completely so it cannot make ajax call. import 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' and make some css changes

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we were missing the `data_url`, or `data_view` setting.  If you're using the included django admin module, you may just go like this:

```py
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    student = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Student.objects.all(),
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            data_url='/admin/<your_app_name>/student/autocomplete/',
            model=Student,
            search_fields=['name__icontains'],
        )
    )

    subject = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Subject.objects.all(),
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            data_url='/admin/<your_app_name>/subject/autocomplete/',
            model=Subject,
            search_fields=['title__icontains'],
            dependent_fields={'student': 'student'},
        )
    )
```